# Angularjs variable is not recognized in href tag in IE Mobile(windows phone 8)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am developing windows phone 8 app using cordova and angularjs.
Angularjs variable is not recognized inside `href`. My code sample is here:

```
<a href="link/{{id}}">name</a>
```

The `{{id}}` is not recognized and link is not working.

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use interpolated variabled in the `href` of an `<a>` tag then you should be using the [ng-href directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref).

```
<a ng-href="link/{{id}}">name</a>
```